# Would there be any problem if we connect the laundry washing machine drain pipe to the kitchen sink drain?

Tags: kitchens, laundry

We might be getting a small place and the only place for a washer is in the kitchen. Wondering if there are drawbacks of connecting the washer drain directly to the kitchen sink drain instead of a tall pipe. Thanks!

Comment: Yes a problem, it has to be vented

Comment: @Ruskes so is it a problem (your comment above), or not really a problem (your answer below)?

Comment: @Huesmann it is a problem if you do not have a drain vent, it is not a problem if you have drain vent

Comment: Many garbage disposers have a port for a dishwasher, does yours?

Comment: @Gil the GD dishwasher port is smaller than any washing machine hose I've ever seen.

Comment: Would something like an air admittance valve under sink work? https://www.homedepot.com/p/STUDOR-Redi-Vent-with-ABS-Adapter-Air-Admittance-Valve-20362/203158640

Comment: Yep but since it was a washer in the kitchen I goofed and assumed it was a dish washing machine, you never specified.

Answer (score 1):

Some apartment dwellers used to buy washing machines on wheels,  hooking them up to the kitchen tap as a water supply and hooking the drain hose over the sink's edge. You're basically recreating that.

I would worry just a bit about putting fiber from the washing machine through a pipe that has grease from the sink; you may need to be extra vigilant about clogs.

Make sure the drain hose won't act as a siphon. Normally that's done by having it enter a pipe that extends above the highest water level, and having a somewhat loose fit there so air can enter.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a problem.

But do not panic if sink gets filled about half a way during washing machine drain.

It will dump so much water that the kitchen drain gets chocked for a wile. It will drain after that.

Answer (score 0):

Washing machine discharge hoses are routinely just hooked over a sink rim, draining via the existing sink drain. This might even be beneficial to kitchen sink plumbing, as the regular flushing with hot soapy water would tend to combat the build-up of greasey detritus which is so common to kitchen drains.
You need to make sure the drain hose is secure, and that the sink will never be stoppered up when the clothes washer discharges. You will also need to make sure the sink drain can actually handle the large output of most washing machines, as there are many old, undersized and half-clogged kitchen drains that would be overwhelmed.